# When creating an array of linkedlist objects why dont we mention the datatype inside linkedlist when creating the object?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am creating an array of LinkedList objects in java. I wrote the syntax as below and got an error.

```
LinkedList<Integer>[] arr = new LinkedList<Integer>[n];
```

I changed it to

```
LinkedList<Integer>[] arr = new LinkedList[n];
```

and it worked fine.

My question why did the first syntax not work?

Comment: what java version are you using? java 6 ?

Comment: @OAD I am using java 8.

Comment: You need to read up on generic array creation.  Use this: `arr = (LinkedList[])Array.newInstance(LinkedList.class, n);`

Answer (score 0):

You are already declaring integer here. I think saying it again would be redundant?

```
LinkedList<Integer>[] arr
```